# Send request from https web site

Tags: javascript, jquery, tomcat

i'm `using apache tomcat 8` with `spring mvc`.
i'm executing a script with `tampermonkey` on a external web site runing on `https` protocol.

```
    ....
    $.ajax({ 
        url     : 'http://localhost:8080/getfromFoo'  ,  type : 'post', 
        success : function(data) {},        
        error   : function(){ alert("error"); }
    });
```

I got in chrome :

```
Mixed Content: The page at 
'https://www.foo.com/' 
was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 
'http://localhost:8080/getfromFoo'. 
This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

and when I change in ajax url to `https` like this `url : 'https://localhost:8080/getfromFoo'` to `https`

in chrome :

```
POST https://localhost:8080/getfromFoo net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
XHR failed loading: POST "https://localhost:8080/getfromFoo".
```

i got in `apache tomcat` log :

```
nov. 20, 2015 12:31:41 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor process
INFOS: Error parsing HTTP request header
 Note: further occurrences of HTTP header parsing errors will be logged at DEBUG level.
```

Answer (score 0):

The external website is in https and yours isnt, If you are going to do a request to https then you should make the request from https.
Basically what i mean is switch your tomcat to https. if using spring-boot with spring mvc it is really simple just generate a certifciate and add it to the properties like this.

```
server.port:8443
    server.ssl.key-store: keystore.p12
    server.ssl.key-store-password: somepass
    server.ssl.keyStoreType: PKCS12
    server.ssl.keyAlias: tomcat
```

Hope it helps

Comment: thanks it could be a solution but i don't use spring-boot